# ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job group1.JobReport threw an unhandled Exception

Tags: quartz-scheduler

There is a strange problem when generating the report using QUARTZ scheduler

I can generate a report fine! no problem.

the method (reportsBean) works normally, but there is a problem when passing through quartz

Any idea please?? I don't know what to do anymore :/

> 13449 [MyScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell  - Job
>   group1.JobReport threw an unhandled Exception: 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.changes.bean.ReportsBean.createPdfCriticalChanges(ReportsBean.java:104)
>     at com.changes.quartz.JobReport.execute(JobReport.java:36)  at
>   org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)     at
>   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
>   13452 [MyScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger  - Job
>   (group1.JobReport threw an exception. org.quartz.SchedulerException:
>   Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException]   at
>   org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)     at
>   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.changes.bean.ReportsBean.createPdfCriticalChanges(ReportsBean.java:104)
>     at com.changes.quartz.JobReport.execute(JobReport.java:36)  at
>   org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)

reportsbean

```
public class JobReport implements Job {


    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {


        //BasicConfigurator.configure();
        try {
            ReportsBean reportsBean = new ReportsBean();
            reportsBean.createPdfCriticalChanges();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy – hh:mm:ss");
            System.out.println("Rodou: " + dateFormat.format( new Date() ));
        } catch (JRException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class =org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = com/changes/quartz/quartz-config.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
```

web.xml

> ```
> <!-- Inicio Quartz -->
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>QuartzServlet</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>com.changes.quartz.servlet.QuartzServlet</servlet-class>
> </servlet>
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>config-file</param-name>
>         <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
>         <param-value>true</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
>         <param-value>true</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <!-- Fim Quartz -->
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you have a NullPointerException in your ReportsBean.

Since the signature of the Quartz execute method is

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
```

Quartz can only deal with JobExecutionException's that will be thrown within this method. But in your case it gets an unexpected NullPointerException.

To solve this Problem you should remove the cause of the NullPointer.
From the sourcecode above I couldnt figure out the cause of this exception since it occurs within your ReportsBean.

Certainly your method ReportsBean.createPdfCriticalChanges trys to access an uninitialized member.

Comment: how could I try initialize a member, please? Thanks

Comment: You initialize a member when you assign a value to it. For example Integer myInt = 10; Please look at the line 104 of your ReportsBean, since in this line a variable is accessed with value null. If you couldnt figure out the problem you should provide the sourcecode of ReportsBean.

Answer (score 0):

at the line 104: 
`String report FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/web/reports/criticalcr.jrxml");`

Remember: it's working out of quartz.

ReportsBean

```
public void createPdfCriticalChanges() throws JRException,SQLException {
            System.out.println("generating report...");

            String report = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/web/reports/criticalcr.jrxml");
            JasperReport pathjrxml = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
            //JasperReport pathjrxml = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("web/reports/criticalcr.jrxml"); //Funciona com o inicia Agenda em XML "web/reports/changetracker_criticalcr.jrxml"
            JasperPrint printReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(pathjrxml, null, conn.getConn());
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printReport, "/web/reports/changetracker_criticalcr.pdf"); //Funciona com o inicia Agenda em XML "web/reports/criticalcr.pdf"
            System.out.println("report generated!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not  throws JobExecutionExceptionnb use @postController and @override method init

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I solved by putting time greater than current time in table that stores next_fire_time. then restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

*ReportsBean* is not able to create an object on this place. If it's a *Spring* application please use `@Autowired` annotations to fix this issue:

```
@Autowired
ReportsBean reportsBean;
```

Then use call `reportsBean.yourMethod();`.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by creating a Lookup Utils, job was like this :

```
public class LimpezaColetaDadosPessoaJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            this.executar();
        } catch (final BusinessException e) {

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void executar() throws NamingException {
        final ColetorDadosPessoasIntegracaoService service = LookupUtils
                .lookup(ColetorDadosPessoasIntegracaoService.class);
        service.executarLimpezaDaTabela();
    }

}
```